# Increase jquery scroll frequency in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a table header which must stay sticky to the top after scrolling 100px (there's a margin above the table). What I did was set its position to `absolute` and calculate the appropriate `top` value using `$(document).scrollTop()` and then updating its position with `$(document).scroll(function () {...}`. All is well and smooth in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE. In IE, the scrolling of the header is not smooth at all.

I did a test where I printed the value of `(document).scrollTop()` and noticed that, while Firefox and Chrome trigger the scroll event every few pixels, IE triggers it once per wheel movement, whether I scrolled 5 pixels or 500.

Is there some way to increase the frequency of update of the scroll event in IE?

What I already tried:

- Setting the header position to fixed instead of absolute helped, but the table is very large and the problem would then be transfered to the horizontal scroll.
- Using CSS animations with a long delay looks weird and is a bit annoying; a short delay doesn't help and the problem remains.
- Used setInterval to update the header position every 100ms. This is too heavy on the browser and doesn't even work. The result stays the same in IE because the scroll value stays the same until the end of the movement..

Note: I'm only targeting IE11.

Edited: http://jsfiddle.net/5fv5q5fy/2/ I just compiled this fiddle for you to try. I appreciate any help, but please keep in mind that I can't change everything without breaking the rest of my website, which is already pretty heavy in interaction elements.

Comment: I don't understand why I'm being downvoted. Can I improve my question in some way?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19610/improve-jquery-parallax-site-on-scroll

Comment: Hard to say, if we don't have a fiddle to play with

Comment: There have been a lot of issues caused by "Smooth Scrolling". Try testing after you've disabled that.

Comment: Can you put a fiddle to try?

Comment: Dears, I added a fiddle to the OP. Hope you can try it on your browsers and on IE11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can change anything on how Internet Explorer works. Indeed, it behave really badly with IE. What you should do, is using this simple workaround using `fixed` positionning :

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/spysr6dp/)**

```
if (scrollTop > 20) {
    // Stays fixed on top
    $("thead").css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0
    }).closest('table').addClass('scrolling');

} else {
    // Moves with scroll
    $("thead").css({
        position: 'static',
        top: 'auto'
    }).closest('table').removeClass('scrolling');
}
```

Then you can remove this css :

```
thead {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}
```

And add this one :

```
table.scrolling {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

**Edit :**

For more sophisticated integration, you might want to take a look at this ready-made plugin, tested and working fine with Internet Explorer :
**[StickyTableHeaders](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if an horizontal scroll appears, fixed positioning won't solve the problem. I would have to manually scroll with scrollLeft. :/ Maybe If I detect the direction of the scrolling, I could change it from absolute do fixed, but it's such an overkill that I think I'll just live with this. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/spysr6dp/1/

Comment: Well, maybe you should use this plugin then : [StickyTableHeaders](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders). I've tested the demo under IE and it works just fine

Comment: Very nice plugin! Thanks Brewal. Post that as an answer so I can accept that. I will try to integrate that into my app and pray that it doesn't break everything else.

Comment: Ok it is done. The plugin seems to be well coded and then should be easy to integrate.

Comment: This would be the perfect solution, but it's very heavy on my app, maybe because I have 25 rows and columns.

Comment: Hmm, well, maybe another idea would be to `clone()` only the header, make it fixed, and give each of its columns the good width, then make sure to handle a possible horizontal scrolling by shifting it to the x position of the table. But I think using `fixed` positionning is the best